# how to format `time` output

Tags: bash, time

I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 x64. The `time` program has an -f flag but when I run it says `-f` command not found.

```
time -f "%Uu %Ss %er %MkB %C" ./countwords hamlet.txt
```

I'm trying to get the `time` program to output the memory use in addition to the default output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably running `bash` (or `zsh`), which has its own `time` command built-in so that it can time a whole pipeline and not just a single command:

```
type time
  time is a shell keyword

help time
  time: time [-p] pipeline
      Report time consumed by pipeline's execution.
      […]
```

You can see that the built-in `time` command has only an optional `-p` flag.

If you want to use the external `time` command (`/usr/bin/time`) as shown in `man time` you will need to specify it explicitly:

```
command time -f '%Uu %Ss %er %MkB %C' ./countwords hamlet.txt
```